# Исполнение команд в командной строке из Delphi

Tags: delphi, cmd

Есть bat-файл, в нём код: 
`"E:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" -Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "HoShiMin"`

Если этот код вставить вручную в командную строку и выполнить - всё работает, если использовать `ShellExecute(0,nil,'cmd.exe','код из бат-файла',nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL)`, то джава начинает бухтеть и разумеется, ничего не работает. Вопрос: как правильно запустить код из батника в `ShellExecute`?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше используйте `WinExec.` Здесь это уместнее и удобнее. Вот пример:

```
WinExec(Pchar('cmd /c start calc.exe'), 1);
```

Данный код запускает калькулятор, выполняя в `cmd.exe` данный код:

```
start calc.exe
```

**Дальше, думаю, сами разберетесь. =)**

Comment: Тоже не работает... Пишет, что не понимает, что такое -xms8192m.

Comment: Всё равно не получается. Запустить какое-нибудь приложение - пожалуйста, всё работает, но вот именно этот код работать не хочет. `WinExec('cmd /c {код из батника}',1)` - на выходе получаю командную строку с надписью о том, что "E:/`\`Program" не является программой. Если убрать директиву /c - то открывается командная строка в папке, где находится приложение, её вызвавшее (моя программа).

Answer (score 1):

ларчик просто открывается
ShellExecute(0,nil,'cmd.exe','/c код из бат-файла',nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL) и не будет работать

проблема в коде. вы указали просто java, а надо java.exe. Это момент первый. Второй момент. Лучше такие строки выполнения загонять в строковую переменную, а уже ее применить в Shellexecute. Ну и третье. Зачем вы обращаетесь к командной строке, если у вас есть своя команда для выполнения?
попробуйте так

...

var optionstring,startprogram:string;

...

begin

startprogram:='E:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe';

optionstring:='-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -cp "%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "HoShiMin"';

ShellExecute(0,nil,pchar(startprogram),pchar(optionstring),nil,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
попробуйте так, и не забудьте в user ShellApi добавить.
https://office-study.xyz

Answer (score 0):

Можно пробовать код cmd сохранить в bat-ник в директории, откуда запущена программа либо в ту, что указана вами выше, затем программно запустить его. Если программа подразумевает в себе закрытие после завершения работы игры, то по её закрытию прописать удаление bat-ника.
Если уже решили проблему, отпишитесь, пожалуйста, как.